# Magic Hidden Excel Mechanism

Tags: excel, uitableview, formula

I have got a sheet of a customer with a Dropdown List.
By selecting an Item of the DD some magic happens:
a part of the sheet is filled with values and is color-formatted as a table.
But I cannot identify any VBA macro or any formula behind the DD-List action.
What magic automatism is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I believe is happening is that they included some Conditional Formatting in the table. When you change the selection on the drop down list, there may be an INDEX statement that pulls the records for that newly selected drop down.

I would suggest checking by clicking Conditional Formatting in the ribbon and seeing if there any rules under Manage Rules.